# Can no longer run "composer require drupal/swiftmailer"

Tags: 8, composer

I have a module that relies on swiftmailer, and needs the libraries installed. Whenever I've needed to install swiftmailer libraries to a Drupal environment, I've always run this command:

```
composer require drupal/swiftmailer
```

This no longer seems to work. Running this now prompts me for authentication to git.drupal.org, and I don't understand why. Apparently this isn't the same as my drupal.org credentials:

[image: screenshot]

I'm not extremely familiar with Composer and am wondering what I can do here.

Comment: Would be better to paste the terminal output as blockquote into your question instead of attaching it as a screenshot. For readability and searchability.

Comment: try `composer require 'drupal/swiftmailer:^1.0'`

Comment: It looks like it's the coder module that's causing the problem, trying to fetch it from a non-standard repository. Are you using a customised/patched version of that module?

Comment: As far as I know I'm not using a custom or patched version. Thanks @NoSssweat, your comment worked for me.

Comment: Puzzling, but good news you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

I know you're sorted now, but wanted to suggest that this could be because the repository URL for the coder module is using https.

See here:

https://help.github.com/articles/why-is-git-always-asking-for-my-password/

The link at the bottom of that article suggests that you can cache your credentials to avoid the need to enter them when using https:

https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

(I would have commented rather than answered, but it seems I don't have enough reputation to comment yet!)

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be caused by the server git.drupal.org not responding. Excerpt from the posted composer output:

```
Could not resolve host: git.drupal.org; Name or service not known
```

I wonder if the reason it suddenly worked again, might be as simple as the server responding again.

The interesting part of this problem is why `drupal/coder` is installed/updated at all (when requiring `drupal/swiftmailer`) ... It's not Swiftmailer that requires Coder. **Added:** If you used "drupal-composer/drupal-project" as your starting point, Coder is required through `webflo/drupal-core-require-dev`. The question then becomes, why did Composer update Coder when you just required Swiftmailer? (That is a Composer issue.)